# sort dataframe by string and set a new id

Tags: pandas, dataframe, columnsorting

is there a possibility to adjust the strings according to the order for example 1.wav, 2.wav 3.wav etc. and the ID accordingly with ID: 1, 2, 3 etc?
i have already tried several sorting options do any of you have any ideas?
Thank you in advance

[dataframe output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhXRl.png)

```
def createSampleDF(audioPath):
    data = []
    for file in Path(audioPath).glob('*.wav'):
        print(file)
        data.append([os.path.basename(file), file])

    df_dataSet = pd.DataFrame(data, columns= ['audio_name', 'filePath'])
    df_dataSet['ID'] = df_dataSet.index+1
    df_dataSet = df_dataSet[['ID','audio_name','filePath']]
    df_dataSet.sort_values(by=['audio_name'],inplace=True)
    return df_dataSet

def createSamples(myAudioPath,savePath, sampleLength, overlap = 0):
    cutSamples(myAudioPath=myAudioPath,savePath=savePath,sampleLength=sampleLength)
    df_dataSet=createSampleDF(audioPath=savePath)
    return df_dataSet
```

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal example of a `DataFrame` containing two rows as well as your expected output (both in separate code blocks)?

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string, make it an integer, and then sort on multiple columns. See the [pandas.Dataframe.sort_values](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) for more info. If your links are more complicated you may need to design a [regex](https://regex101.com/) to pull out the integers you want to sort on using [pandas.Series.str.extract](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html).

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'ID':[1,2,3,4, 5],
'audio_name' : ['1.wav','10.wav','96.wav','3.wav','55.wav']})
```

[image]

```
(df
.assign(audio_name=lambda df_ : df_.audio_name.str.split('.', expand=True).iloc[:,0].astype('int'))
.sort_values(by=['audio_name','ID']))
```

[image]